# React Function Components - following parent component state

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying component functional style.
I have simple todo list. I would like to strike out todo item from list using style property. From Chrome debug mode I do not see immediate reaction on checkbox changes, also Item is not striked out... It seams to me, that it is problem with how I manage state of components. I would appreciate some guidance.

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Todos from "./components/Todos";

import './App.css'

const App = () => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState(
        [
            {id: 1, title: 'Take out the trash', completed: false},
            {id: 2, title: 'Dinner with wife', completed: false},
            {id: 3, title: 'Meeting boss', completed: false}
        ]
    );

    const markComplete = id => {
        console.log((new Date()).toString());

        todos.map(todo => {
            if (todo.id === id) {
                todo.completed = ! todo.completed;
            }
            return todo;
        });
        setTodos(todos);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Todos todos={todos} markComplete={markComplete}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Todos.js

```
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";

const Todos = ({todos, markComplete}) => {
    return (
        todos.map(todo => (
            <TodoItem key={todo.id} todoItem={todo} markComplete={markComplete} />
        ))
    );
};

export default Todos;
```

TodoItem.js

```
import React from "react";

const TodoItem = ({todoItem, markComplete}) => {
    const getStyle = () => {
        console.log("style: " + todoItem.completed);
        return {
            background: '#f4f4f4',
            padding: '10px',
            borderBottom: '1px #ccc dotted',
            textDecoration: todoItem.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
        }
    };

    return (
        <div style={getStyle()}>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={markComplete.bind(this, todoItem.id)}/>{' '}
                {todoItem.title}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TodoItem;
```

I expect that this getStyle() will follow state... somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new Array, which you are throwing away. You need to use the new array, e.g.:

```
const markComplete = id => {
  ...
  setTodos(totos.map(...))
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't mutate state. In `markComplete` function, you are mutating the `todos` array directly. Change your function like this to avoid mutation

```
const markComplete = id => {
   console.log((new Date()).toString());
   let newTodos = todos.map(todo => {
       let newTodo = { ...todo };
       if (newTodo.id === id) {
           newTodo.completed = !newTodo.completed;
       }
       return newTodo;
    });
    setTodos(newTodos);
};
```

Comment: `Don't mutate state` is generally good advice, though the OP wasn't mutating the `todos` array directly, only the objects inside the array (not a good pattern, but does no harm in this case AFAIK)

Comment: Should I copy whole array on each change? Or just change ref? I mean we apply whole new object on each object property change?

Comment: If the state is an array, it must be set to a new array for React to detect change of state. So yes in your case. If state was an object, it would be that top-level object that must be copied. While it is MUCH simpler to work with deep copies and/or immutable types in React state, it is not strictly necessary.